# How to retrieve timestamp field in EST time zone in Teradata SQL

Tags: teradata

My Requirement is, I have Table in teradata which has a timestamp field in UTC. While soing a select statement i need to display the timestamp field in EST. Need Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need daylight saving time?

```
TS_column AT 'America Eastern'
```

Without DST:

```
TS_column AT -5
```